# How methods are inherited in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I am having the following Classes:

```
package com.zee.main;
import com.zee.sub.Sub;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        sub.add();
    }
}

package com.zee.sup;
public class Super 
{
    private int a = 2;
    private int b = 3;

    public void add(){
        System.out.println("Result: "+(a+b));
        System.out.println("Class:" +this.getClass().getName());        
    }
}

package com.zee.sub;
import com.zee.sup.Super;

public class Sub extends Super {
}
```

**Output:**

```
Result: 5
Class:com.zee.sub.Sub
```

How do a `Subclass` inherit the method of its `Superclass`? I was in the assumption that the method defined in the `Superclass` becomes the part of `Subclass` but when I checked the compiled bytecode of Sub, I found that there is no `add` method that was defined in the Super class.

```
// Compiled from Sub.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
public class com.zee.sub.Sub extends com.zee.sup.Super {

  // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  public Sub();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  invokespecial com.zee.sup.Super() [8]
    4  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 5]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: com.zee.sub.Sub
}
```

Following are my questions:

1. Since there is no `add` method in the compiled bytecode of Sub, the `add` method of `Superclass` must have been called at runtime.
2. Contradicting the first point is the `this.getClass().getName()` which returns the runtime class of this Object, but its printing `Sub` as the runtime class.
3. If the runtime class is Sub, then how it is accessing the private fields `a` and `b` of the Superclass in its `add` method?

Can someone please explain. Thanks in advance

Comment: I like how you are looking at bytecode, but don't understand inheritance. In the bytecode of `MainClass` what's the corresponding instruction for invoking `add`?

Comment: There are multiple errors with your source code.

From [Creating a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html):

"The package statement (for example, package graphics;) must be the first line in the source file. There can be only one package statement in each source file, and it applies to all types in the file."

"If you put multiple types in a single source file, only one can be public"

Comment: @DavidPostill Those are clearly separate files in their project that are just represented here as a single code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "questions" aren't exactly questions, but to respond to them:

- If you disassembled the `main` method, you'd see a call to `invokevirtual` for `add()`. This tells the JVM to look up the appropriate method to call in the class hierarchy, starting with the subclass and working its way up if it doesn't find an implementation there.
- `Object#getClass()` is one of the special infrastructure methods in Java. [It's implemented with `native` code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Object.java#Object.getClass%28%29) and hooks into the JVM internals to identify the class of the object in question.
- The class `Sub` *doesn't* access the private members. The code in `Super` accesses them.

Comment: To expand on the answer to the second question.  When an instance method is called, the value of 'this' is passed to the method.  Thus the method knows which object it is being invoked on, and an object knows which class it instantiated.

Comment: So even though `add` method of `Super` is getting called, value of `this` inside the `add` method will be pointing to `Sub`?

Comment: No, there's only one object, which is *both* a `Super` and a `Sub`. The code in the `add` method is directly accessing the fields inside `Super`.

Comment: Only one object? We we create a new subclass object, doesn't the superclass no-arg constructor is called first creating a superclass object before the subclass. So we should be having two different object?? Am i missing something??

Comment: @LoneRider Apparently. There is only *one object*. That object is both a `Super` and a `Sub` (and an `Object`). The constructors are called in hierarchy order to perform necessary setup of the pieces contributed by each class, but you only have one object.

Comment: hmmmm. Thanks for your response. I guess I need to study more about how classes are loaded and invoked.

Answer (score 2):

> Since there is no add method in the compiled bytecode of Sub, the add
>   method  of Superclass must have been called at runtime.

Yes, method calls are by definition a runtime procedure.

> Contradicting the first point is the this.getClass().getName() which
>   returns  the runtime class of this Object, but its printing Sub as the
>   runtime class.

There is no contradiction here.  The `add()` method is defined in the superclass, it is not redefined in the subclass, and so when `add` is called on the subclass, the method from the superclass is invoked.

> If the runtime class is Sub, then how it is accessing the private
>   fields a and  b of the Superclass in its add method?

It is accessing them by virtue of being a method within the superclass, which has access to that class' private instance variables.  Normal scope rules apply.

This may help you overall: as I understand it, when a class is put together, there is what we may think of as a list of methods in a table.  When a method is invoked, really what happens is that the address of the correct method is retrieved from this "jump table".  In the case at hand, the place in the jump table for `add()` is occupied by the address from the superclass method.  That method, in turn, has offsets for accessing things like the private variables; the setup of the class cleverly puts them at the same offsets in both the subclass and superclass so they'll work in both places.

So the `add` method invoked for the subclass is really the same method, using the same instance variable locations, as it would be for the superclass.

I hope that helps explain things.

Comment: _The add() method is defined in the superclass, it is not redefined in the subclass, and so when add is called on the subclass, the method from the superclass is invoked._    Why `this` inside `add` of Super is pointing to SubClass?

Comment: The `this` keyword in any method refers to the object itself.  If you have instantiated a subclass, then it points to an instance of the subclass, etc.  When you extend a class and instantiate the subclass, you do NOT get two objects;  you get ONE object with the characteristics inherited from the superclass and any that are defined or redefined in the subclass.

Answer (score -2):

Sub can access private fields from Superclass because Sub is of type Superclass and it gains access to these private fields when calling upon methods defined in Superclass.  It, however, can not call upon these fields when you attempt to make methods that will only belong to the Sub class due to Superclass privatizing "direct" access to these fields from its children.

Comment: Your wording is extremely convoluted.

Comment: "*Sub can access private fields from Superclass because Sub is of type Superclass*" that is wrong. Subclass doesn't have access to private members of its super class. In this case it has access to `add` method which has access to private fields of super class because it is also member of this class. Private means that access to this member is restricted only to class itself (which includes its other members: fields, methods, inner/nested classes).

Comment: @Pshemo To be fair, you'd have to read the whole sentence, but the explanation is very unclear.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, my comments was not meant to refer entire answer but only its first sentence which seems to mean something different than described in rest of answer.